# match inside a match

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have a simple string:

```
data1:abc,123,xyz,data2:hello,goodbye
```

I need regex to return a match collection of:

```
abc
123
xyz
```

In the past I'd do it with a regular expression:

```
data1:(.*)data2:
```

and then split the output of that on the comma.

Is there a way to do this as one regular expression and no external code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
String text = "data1:abc,123,xyz,data2:hello,goodbye";
Regex reg = new Regex(@"(?<=data1:.*)[^,]+(?=.*data2)");

MatchCollection result = reg.Matches(text);

foreach (var item in result) {
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

output:

> abc
>   123
>   xyz

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you can do soemthing like

```
String s="data1:abc,123,xyz,data2:hello,goodbye "
sttring[] slst= s.split(":");

for (int i = 0;i<slst.lemgth;i++)
{
 string[] inr = slst[i].split(",");
 for (int j = 0;j<inr.lemgth;j++)
 {
   if((inr.IndexOf("data") != -1)
    continue;
    //your code  
 }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input but I need to do this without any code, just the regular expression.

Comment: Why you need *only* regex solution?

Comment: Because this is actually a configuration value I pass into an application and I didn't want to add more code to the solution.  Passing in a fully formed Regex that did this work for me saves me recoding a core method.